# ReactJs prints new state value even printed before changing it

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable called data and I am setting it's value as 'First' then I am changing the value to 'Second' and displaying again so my output should be

First
Second

But it prints

Second
Second

I would appreciate if you can tell me why I am getting Second and Second instead of First and Second. And if you could tell me how can I achieve First and Second.

Here is my code snippet.

```
<script type="text/babel">

   var FirstDiv = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function() {
          return {data:'First'};
      },
      changeStateVal: function() {
          this.setState({data:'Second'});
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data} <br/>
                {this.changeStateVal()}
                {this.state.data}
            </div>
        );
      }
   });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <FirstDiv />,
        document.getElementById('first')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. Calling `setState` in `render` is a no-no and doesn't make sense (see also [the `render` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render)). In general, React components are *declarative*. `render` returns a representation of your component for its current state. Changing the component's state during render doesn't make sense since it (in theory) causes the component to rerender. Reading [a tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) might help understanding React better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I guess this is happening because of the component is getting rerender. I probably need to read more documentation about ReactJS to avoid such mistakes.